# Delphi SqLite Date load to TDateEdit error

Tags: sqlite, delphi, datetime, firedac, delphi-10.1-berlin

I using SQlite database im my Firemonkey Android application and there is no native DateTime type.

I storing date as text type

insert command:

```
insert into table (value,date_of_change)
values (:val,date('now'));
```

it works fine, date is correct stored, order by date works fine but if I want load this date into TDate edit

query:

```
select id,value,date_of_change
from table
where id = :MyID
```

code:

```
FDQuery1.Close;
FDQuery1.ParamByName('MyID').Value:= myid;
FDQuery1.OpenOrExecute;
FDQuery1.First;

NumberBox1.Value:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('suma').AsFloat;
DateEdit1.Date:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('date_of_change').AsDateTime;
```

I get error **2016-10-16 is not valid date and time** but in Date edit I can see correct date !

Do anybody knows correct solution of this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you store the date as a string FireDAC fails to parse the format properly. You need to change the way the string value in the database column `date_of_change` is parsed using the correct date format.

So, instead of doing this:

```
DateEdit1.Date:=FDQuery1.FieldByName('date_of_change').AsDateTime;
```

You should do this:

```
function ParseDateFromDB(const DateStr: String): TDateTime;
var
  FormatSettings: TFormatSettings;
begin
  FormatSettings.DateSeparator := '-';
  FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat := 'YYYY-MM-DD';
  Result := StrToDate(DateStr, FormatSettings);
end;

//[...]

DateEdit1.Date := ParseDateFromDB(FDQuery1.FieldByName('date_of_change').AsString);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine now !
But now I have reverse problem ... I need save date form DateEdit and this code `FDCommand1.ParamByName('date_of_change').Value:= dateedit1.Date;`  save 2016-10-16 as 459-09-11

Comment: I thinked that TDate type has treated this things !

Comment: See the documentation for `FormatDateTime`: http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=formatdatetime

Comment: I know about this article, but I need solution which works with any date local format. For example I using europan date coding dd-mm-yyyy but I need my aplication works corectly with any local settings

Comment: store the date as a datetime format, not as string and all your problems will be solved...

Answer (score 0):

FireDAC uses its own [**mapping to SQLite data types**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_SQLite_with_FireDAC#Mapping_SQLite_to_FireDAC_Data_Types) and adds the **DATE** pseudo data type for you. So as there is the **SINGLE** pseudo data type that you can use for storing value of that number box.

So you can create your table by FireDAC like this:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'CREATE TABLE MyTable (DateField DATE, SingleField SINGLE)';
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
```

Then you can insert data:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO MyTable (DateField, SingleField) VALUES (:DateField, :SingleField)';
FDQuery.ParamByName('DateField').AsDate := DateEdit.Date;
FDQuery.ParamByName('SingleField').AsSingle := NumberBox.Value;
FDQuery.ExecSQL;
```

And read them for example this way:

```
FDQuery.SQL.Text := 'SELECT DateField, SingleField FROM MyTable';
FDQuery.Open;
DateEdit.Date := DateOf(FDQuery.FieldByName('DateField').AsDateTime);
NumberBox.Value := FDQuery.FieldByName('SingleField').AsSingle;
```